# Niolocker is not working in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, locking, spring-integration, nio

Trying to test file lock mechanism in spring boot application by starting  two instances of same application pointing to same source path which contains 10 files. Expecting only one instance should process a file and once processed it will be deleted from source. Same file should not be processed by other instance.So added Niolocker to the scanner. Tested in both windows and linux environments.But in windows, facing below exception in both the instances... In Linux, same file is polled/processed by both instances. No impact in Linux. Have implemented the below logic to acquire lock.

Please suggest on this.

**Windows exception:**

java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file

**Linux:**
Both instance poller picks the same file and processing it

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesInChannel" directory="file:${base.path}" auto-startup="false" scanner="recursiveScanner" auto-create-directory="true">
  <integration:poller id="poller" max-messages-per-poll="${max.messages.per.poll}" fixed-rate="${message.read.frequency}" task-executor="pollingExecutor">
    <integration:transactional transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
  </integration:poller>
  </file:inbound-channel-adapter>


<bean id="inboundFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
     <constructor-arg>
         <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptOnceFileListFilter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.RegexPatternFileListFilter">
                <constructor-arg value="${file.type}"/>
           </bean>
         </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="inboundChannelNioLocker" class="org.springframework.integration.file.locking.NioFileLocker" /> 

<bean id="recursiveScanner" class="org.springframework.integration.file.RecursiveDirectoryScanner">
        <property name="filter" ref="inboundFilter" />
        <property name="locker" ref="inboundChannelNioLocker"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `NioLocker` is really operation system dependent and doesn't guarantee exclusive access to the file. Well, only Windows does that for us properly.

I even start considering to deprecate and remove it altogether from the Framework. It causes too much confuses for target users...

Instead of file locker you need to consider to use a `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` based on the shared `ConcurrentMetadataStore`. So, this way really only one instance will pick up the file for processing. All others will skip it and move on to the next files.

See [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/files.html#file-reading) for more info.

Comment: In my case , Don't have any share metadata store to implement above approach. Is there any other way like changing the file name once reading like samplefile.reading and change it to original name while placing in destination (samplefile). Can you share some examples link.

Comment: There is no such a link. We just don't have any samples on the matter since each use-case is really unique and requires its own approach and implementation. I can suggest to implement a custom `FileLocker` and try create there an additional file - `fileToLock.getName() + ".lock"` and check for its existence for `boolean` return. Then in the end of process you just go and remove that `.lock` file.

Comment: Fine will try this..need some clarification... I tried your first option...FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter with metadata store as PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore . Would like to know what is the second value we are passing for constructor...FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter Java.lang.string Prefix.. what is the purpose of it? It defines filename prefix.. if so in my case there is no defined prefix name for files... could you clarify on this

Comment: The prefix is used when the mentioned the same `MetadataStore` is shared  between different components. Then this prefix is added to each `key` stored in the metadata. You can leave it as `""` (empty string), if you prefer to stay away from the prefix

Comment: Implemented FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter  solution as suggested. But still facing same issue. provided details in separate question. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52047650/filesystemacceptoncefilelistfilter-is-not-working

Comment: @ArtemBilan do PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore support cluster (multiple instance)?

Comment: Correct, if you use some shared meta data store. See docs about info